# connect current time and date to the timeEdit and dateEdit in qt

Tags: qt

in qt, I want to connect the current time with the timeEdit so when I launch the application, the time progresses.
I wrote this:

```
    QDate myD = iDate->currentDate();
    QTime myT = iTime->currentTime();


    ui->dateEdit->setDate(myD);
    ui->timeEdit->setTime(myT);
    
    connect (dte, SIGNAL(getDate(myD)), ui->dateEdit, SLOT(setDate(myD)));

    connect(dte, &QTimeEdit::timeChanged, ui->timeEdit,&QTimeEdit::setTime);
```

NB:  `QDateTimeEdit* dte = new QDateTimeEdit;` declared in the .h file.
when I launch the app, the time is still freezing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in the example code that is running to update the time. I would think you would need to start a 1 second timer and every timeout you update the QDateTimeEdit with the current QDateTime::currentDateTime.

Something like this:

```
QTimer* updatetimer = new QTimer();
connect(updatetimer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &UiClass::UpdateTimerTimeout)
updateTimer->start(1000);

UpdateTimerTimeout {
    ui->dateEdit->setDate(QDateTime::currentDateTime().date());
    ui->timeEdit->setTime(QDateTime::currentDateTime().time());
}
```

Something like that should do what you want.